# Get value from custom Cypress.Commands

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to retrieve data from API and compare this data with text from UI. For this I created Custom.Command that takes value from API:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('responseApi', ()=>{
    cy.request('http://api')
      .then(r=>{
        let body = JSON.parse(r.body.account.price)
        let res = body.toString()
//console.log(res) If I print the value here it returns the value in console
        return res
      })
})
```

Then I am trying to verify if something returns, but I don't see the value in console, seems like it doesn't return anything.

```
it('Import account', ()=>{
   cy.responseApi(r=>console.log(r))
}
```

Comment: browser console or node console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom command returns a Chainer object which has a `.then()` method that provides the returned value. The brackets are for input parameters.

```js
cy.responseApi('<input parameters passed here>').then(r => console.log(r))
```

A full working example

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('responseApi', ()=>{
  cy.request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      return response.body
    })
})

it('gets an api value', () => {
  cy.responseApi()
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .should('deep.eq', {
      userId: 1, 
      id: 1, 
      title: "delectus aut autem", 
      completed: false
    })
})
```